# Modifiying class attribute of parent

Tags: python, inheritance

I recently encountered the following phenomenon and couldn't understand why it happens.

Consider the following:

```py
class A:
     my_var = 0
     def __init__(self):
         type(self).my_var += 1 
class B(A):
     pass
```

This results in:

```py
In [3]: A.my_var is B.my_var
Out[3]: True

In [4]: A()
In [5]: A.my_var is B.my_var
Out[5]: True
In [6]: A.my_var
Out[6]: 1
In [7]: B.my_var
Out[7]: 1
```

But then:

```py
In [8]: B()
In [9]: A.my_var is B.my_var
Out[9]: False
In [10]: A.my_var
Out[10]: 1
In [11]: B.my_var
Out[11]: 2
```

I do not understand why initiazling `B()`, casues `my_var` to "fork".

Comment: `type(self)` returns `B` when you call `B()`, so you are creating a new class attribute in `B` rather than updating `A.my_var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `B()`, `B.__init__` resolves to `A.__dict__['init']`, since you did not override `B.__init__`. But `type(self)` still returns `B`, because it's an instance of `B`, not `A`, being initialized. As a result, you create `B.my_var`.

The assignment to an attribute is what makes this different from something like `x += y`, where `x` has to be defined in the current scope to avoid an `UnboundLocalError` exception. `type(self).my_var += 1` "desugars" to `B.my_var = B.my_var + 1`. (`type(self)` has to be evaluated first to identify on which type to find the `__iadd__` attribute.) On the right-hand side, `B.__dict__['my_var']` is not defined, so it evaluates to `A.my_var`. On the *left*, the attribute is created.